# JPEG2000 for Python

Tags: python, jpeg2000

I am about to run a simulation in which I need to encode and decode image files with JPEG2000. I need an API that gives me the flexibility to set coding rate (or quality of the compressed file). Is there any API for Python to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.4.0 [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/pillow/) supports most JPEG 2000 files as explained [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000) - *the exception being files with mixed sampling rates*.

Pillow is:

- a maintained fork of PIL
- pip installable with `pip install Pillow`
- gives you a huge range of image manipulation options & file type support
- currently at version 5.2.0 so it has supported JPEG 2000 for a long time
- pretty much the standard library for image manipulation

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for it personally, but a quick Google search yielded [Glymur](https://glymur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) which looks to be exactly what you are asking for. From the into page:

> **Glymur** is an interface to the OpenJPEG library which allows one to
>   read and write JPEG 2000 files from Python. Glymur supports both
>   reading and writing of JPEG 2000 images, but writing JPEG 2000 images
>   is currently limited to images that can fit in memory. Glymur can read
>   images using OpenJPEG library versions as far back as 1.3, but it is
>   strongly recommended to use at least version 2.1.2.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I was aware of this package, but it does not offer the parameter control I need due to the best of my knowledge.